# Make stow create symlinks to absolute paths?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I like using `stow` to store dotfiles in a separate directory that I can track with version control and that is stored on a separate (internal) disk.

When I stow a directory, I notice that `stow` creates a symlink to my separate internal disk using a relative path, for example `../../mnt/extra-space/Workspaces/dotfiles/and/so/on`. I would prefer to have a symlink to `/mnt/extra-space/Workspaces/dotfiles/and/so/on`.

Can I do this with `stow` or would I need to create those symlinks directly with `ln`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My `man stow` says

> Stow only creates relative symlinks.

in the paragraph just before "Options".

Comment: Also [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html#Terminology).